# Hola, tengo un aareglo de json con su index y sus montos, pero quisiera reagruparlos

Tags: javascript, array, json

El arreglo es el siguiente:

> var lineas = [{linea: 1, monto: 24} , {linea: 2, monto: 35}, {linea:3, monto: -23}, {linea:4, monto: -14} , {linea: 5, monto: -10}, {linea: 6, monto: 12}]

El resultado que quiero es

> [{linea: 1, monto: 24}], [{linea: 2, monto: 35}, {linea:3, monto: -23}, {linea:4, monto: -14} , {linea: 5, monto: -10}], [{linea: 6, monto: 12}]

Es decir, si se tiene una línea con monto positivo y la que sigue también es monto positivo entonces solo se queda la primera línea. Pero si se tiene una línea positiva y la que sigue es negativa, esta se tiene que agrupar con la positiva y deja de agruparse cuando se encuentra con un monto positivo.

Intenté con un `for` pero solo me agrupa con el primer negativo que encuentra y la idea es que agrupe a todos los negativos que encuentre debajo de esa línea positiva.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].